# Get added camera in three js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, addition

I have an object `car` to whom I `add` camera. How can I access the camera through this object now. I've tried this:

```
car = {};
car.body = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 5, 7 ),
    Physijs.createMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: color }), .8, .2 ), 
    1000 );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
var pos = car.body.position;
camera.position.set(pos.x + 75, pos.y + 20, pos.z);
camera.lookAt( pos );
car.body.add(camera);

//...

// other function

var camera = car.body.camera;
```

but I get an error saying `THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.`

Is this even possible or do I have to keep the camera(s) in some global variable(array)?

Comment: I have not used Phyisijs, but why would you do this? `car.body.add(camera);`? If you wanted the car.body to have a reference to the camera wouldn't you just do `car.body.camera = camera;`?

Comment: @2pha Didn't know I could do that, does `body` have an attribute `camera`? Give me a minute

Comment: It works, but now `camera` won't follow the `car` anymore

Comment: Hard to help without seeing more of your code and knowing what is happening in your render loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a reference to the camera within the car.body.
Use:

```
car.body.camera = camera;
```

instead of:

```
car.body.add(camera);
```

Comment: I have tested with `add` and `=` and if i use the latter, camera doesn't follow the car anymore

Comment: That is because when you use `car.body.add(camera)`, the camera is added as a child of car.body, so will move with car.body. But when just adding a reference to camera in car.body `car.body.camera = camera;`, it is just that, a reference. You could go back to using `car.body.add(camera);` but then you would have to retrieve it by looking in the `car.body.children` array.

Comment: Thanks, I solved with an additional array that stores all the cameras